# How to prevent showing Thank You Page except redirect from PayPal

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I have a WordPress Based Website build on OptimizePress Theme. I'm selling my goods in here. I'm using PayPal payment option only. I'm using 'Thank You' Page redirection after successful payment. Now my Thank You Page showing directly. Any One can access here.

My problem is I don't want to show 'Thank You' page other than the successful PayPal Payment screen.

Comment: Just I'm puzzled how to do it?

Comment: If memory serves correctly, I believe PayPal puts some query strings into the "thank you" page's URL when it does its redirection.  You could use those to verify that a transaction actually took place.  For example, if the PayPal transaction ID is passed via a query string, you could look that up in your database to see whether a transaction with that ID was recently posted.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`session`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). Set session at payment page. get session at thank you page.If that session is set show thank you page(and also clear session),else do what you want (may be redirect home page.).

**Note**

It does not matter if people visit your thank you page by typing the URL.